# Read all files in ascending order to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, matplotlib

I am trying to read around 200 files in a directory into an array sequentially:
2 approaches:

```
results = [open(f) for f in glob.glob("*.bin")]
```

here, this gave me an error that lot of files are opened.

```
for f in glob.glob("*.bin"):
print f
```

This gives me an unordered list and I am not sure how to use `sorted(f,key=itemgetter(0))`

Also, Once I read file 0 into an array, I need to do some array ordering and then concatenate with the data from file 1 and so on till the last file in the directory (Assuming that file 0, file 1 are in ascending order). For this, I declare x0 = 0 and then concatenate it this way:

```
x = numpy.concatenate((x0, x), axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions !

Edit 1:

I tried your method in this way:

```
x0 = numpy.zeros(shape=(1026, 718))
f = sorted(glob.glob('*.bin'))
for f in sorted(glob.glob('*.bin')):
    print f ## prints files ordered
    x = numpy.concatenate((x0, x), axis=1) 
    x0 = x
```

I get the following error:

```
x = numpy.concatenate((x0, x), axis=1) 
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably want to only have one file open at a time:

```
def my_open(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return numpy.loadtxt(f)
```

If you just need sorted order like `ls` would do, you can pass a list through `sorted`. If you need something fancier, see the [sorting howto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

If you can fit all the records into half your available memory, this is probably a bit faster:

```
numpy.concatenate(map(my_open, sorted(glob('*.bin'))))
```

Otherwise you can concatenate in a loop and save memory:

```
arr = numpy.zeros()
for path in sorted(glob('*.bin')):
    arr = numpy.concatenate((arr, my_open(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about what error you're getting.  Are you trying to sort by filename?  Then it would make more sense to do so on the list of filenames returned:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*.bin'))
```

Then you can go through the list of filenames and successively read the files to extract the data you need.

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob('*.bin')):
    f = open(filename)
    # Perform your necessary array ordering
    # Concatenate the data
```

If you want to do this backward, that is read the data from your last file into `x`, then read and append the data from the second to last, then just change your sort to

```
sorted(glob.glob('*.bin'), reverse = True)
```